# Why the message displays in console correctly, but the return doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm in a Codewars challenge, called 'zombie onslaught'.

The task is: given three arguments (n° of zombies, initial zombie position/distance, n° of ammo)
I have to return a message based on some conditions.

If the zombies are all dead I should return: **'`You killed all ${x} zombies`'**

If there are still zombies around but you run out of ammo I should return: **'`You shot ${x} zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo.`'**

if I've got ammo but the distance is 0 I should return **'`You shot ${x} zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.`'**

In the end if I've runned out of ammo and the distance is 0 too, I should return **'`You shot ${x} zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.`'**

Now the problem is that the message displays correctly in **console.log()**, but I need to return it, and the return is just an `undefined`

Here's the code, it's a short function so i post it all here.

```
function zombie_shootout(zombies, range, ammo) {

    let currentZombies = zombies
    let currentRange = range
    let currentAmmo = ammo
    let killedZombies = 0
    let message = ''

    setInterval(() => {
        currentZombies -= 1
        currentRange -= 0.5
        currentAmmo -= 1

        if (currentZombies === 0) {
            message = `You shot all ${currentZombies} zombies`

        } else if (currentZombies > 0 && currentAmmo === 0) {
            killedZombies = zombies - currentZombies
            message = `You shot ${killedZombies} zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo.`

        } else if (currentAmmo > 0 && currentRange === 0) {
            killedZombies = zombies - currentZombies
            message = `You shot ${killedZombies} zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.`

        } else if (currentAmmo === 0 && currentRange === 0) {
            killedZombies = zombies - currentZombies
            message = `You shot ${killedZombies} zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.`
        }
        
    }, 1000)

    return message

}
```

The **message** variable that is returned at the end it always returns `undefined`

Could you help me guys? Cause in the console the results are correct, so everything seems to work fine.

Here's some test cases

```
zombie_shootout(3, 10, 10) // => "You shot all 3 zombies."
zombie_shootout(100, 8, 200) // => "You shot 16 zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed." 
zombie_shootout(50, 10, 8) // => "You shot 8 zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo."
```

Comment: At the point that `message` is returned, no value has been assigned.

Comment: Have a look at what `setInterval()` does. And why your current setup cannot work at all.

Comment: Why do you use `setInterval()` at all in your function? o.O

Comment: Yes, surely the setInterval needs to be modified. But I tried to put the if statements out of the interval, it didn't work.

Comment: @D.D. Show the code you tried *without* `setInterval`, and explain what "didn't work" means.

Comment: Cause every one second the distance is smaller, one zombie is being killed and ammo reduces by one also.

Comment: you should return value inside the setInterval method because your message in generated after a second and you are returning value earlier

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` takes time and javascript is `Synchronous` by default, javaScript does not wait for the setInterval to execute. you can use `async/await` or `promises`